# org.apache.commons.mail.util.MimeMessageParser never ends parsing

Tags: java, email, apache-commons-email

I have some code to parse incoming mails. I use org.apache.commons.mail.util.MimeMessageParser for this.The problem occurs in the following method:

```
private String getActionDescription(Message message) throws Exception {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = (MimeMessage)message;
    MimeMessageParser mmp = new MimeMessageParser(mimeMessage);
    mmp.parse(); // !!! sometimes my code hangs here; inside this parse method
    String description = mmp.getHtmlContent();
    if(Utils.isNullOrEmpty(description)) {
        description = mmp.getPlainContent();
        if(description != null) {
            description = description.replace("\r\n", "<br>");
        }
    }
    return description;
}
```

Most of the time it works fine, but every few days my code gets stuck inside mmp.parse(). I don't get any exception or timeout. It just stops.

Anyone can shed any light on this?

Kind regards.

P.S.: if you need more info, just ask and I'll add it here.

apache jar version: commons-email-1.5.jar

jdk version: 11

my imports:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.apache.commons.mail.util.MimeMessageParser;
```

Comment: How do you know that `parse()` never returns?

Comment: And if it's really the case, you should provide an example of such a mail (for example an .eml file).

Comment: I put some logging right before and right after that line...it never returns...it just hangs. It's not so easy to provide an email with wich the problem occurrs since it occurs only every few days/weeks, but I'll try to get one.

Comment: What version of commons-email are you using? Also can you check which types of messages are getting stuck (check MimeMessage content type) ?

Comment: I was thinking to solve this by creating a new thread with a timeout to do the parsing and waiting for the result in the main thread. That way I can skip mails that cause a timeout.

Comment: commons-email-1.5.jar

Comment: hi Tom, it would be best if you could post your jdk version. just in case.

Comment: I use JDK version 11

Comment: Are you sure the method doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: yes, I am sure.

Comment: Could you give some examples of a problem message, please?

Comment: Also please show your imports

Comment: @Tom After the line `String description = mmp.getHtmlContent();`  add `System.out.println(descreption)` to check whether it is parsing or not.

Comment: I added that println right before and after String description = mmp.getHtmlContent(); It is not parsing, it just hangs, I am sure

Comment: I added my imports to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding following properties when getting a mail session solved the problem:

```
mail.imap.partialfetch false
mail.imap.fetchsize 1048576
```

Mails with big attachments slowed parsing down extremely. These settings greatly improved network IO to the mail server for big attachments.